# Porque o for-loop converte de Date para integer?

Tags: r, data, for

Alguém sabe explicar porque no `for-loop` os objetos `Date` são convertidos para `integer`?
No código abaixo eu quero iterar nas datas mas estas são convertidas para inteiros.

```
> dates <- Sys.Date() + 1:10
> dates
 [1] "2015-09-29" "2015-09-30" "2015-10-01" "2015-10-02" "2015-10-03" "2015-10-04" "2015-10-05" "2015-10-06" "2015-10-07" "2015-10-08"
> for (date in dates) print(date)
[1] 16707
[1] 16708
[1] 16709
[1] 16710
[1] 16711
[1] 16712
[1] 16713
[1] 16714
[1] 16715
[1] 16716
```

Se eu uso uma lista isso não acontece.

```
> for (date in as.list(dates)) print(date)
[1] "2015-09-29"
[1] "2015-09-30"
[1] "2015-10-01"
[1] "2015-10-02"
[1] "2015-10-03"
[1] "2015-10-04"
[1] "2015-10-05"
[1] "2015-10-06"
[1] "2015-10-07"
[1] "2015-10-08"
```

Alguém sabe o motivo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Adaptação da resposta do SOen [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6434822/724200))

A página de help (`` ?`for` ``) diz o seguinte:

> An expression evaluating to a vector (including a list and an expression) or to a pairlist or NULL.

Como objetos da classe `Date` não são vetores, são convertidos em um:

```
> is.vector(Sys.Date())
[1] FALSE
> is.vector(as.numeric(Sys.Date()))
[1] TRUE
```

Quando você usa uma lista, você transforma o objeto em um vetor (listas são vetores):

```
> is.vector(as.list(dates))
[1] TRUE
```

A diferença de usar `as.list()` para `as.vector()` (que deve ser análogo ao usado internamente no `for`) é que o primeiro mantém a classe `Date` dos elementos (pois uma lista pode ser heterogênea e conter qualquer coisa), e o segundo faz a conversão para `numeric`.

```
> sapply(as.list(dates), class)
[1] "Date" "Date" "Date" "Date" "Date" "Date" "Date" "Date" "Date" "Date"
```

Outra alternativa relativamente simples é fazer o loop em uma sequência do tamanho do objeto de datas e fazer o subset:

```
> for (date in seq_along(dates)) print(dates[date])
[1] "2015-09-29"
[1] "2015-09-30"
[1] "2015-10-01"
[1] "2015-10-02"
[1] "2015-10-03"
[1] "2015-10-04"
[1] "2015-10-05"
[1] "2015-10-06"
[1] "2015-10-07"
[1] "2015-10-08"
```